# Use globalize3 (with_translation) with 2 models in a query (include)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, globalize3

Using Globalize3 I am trying to load the following models including translations in a single query:

- products (with product_translations)
- properties (with property_translations)

When I try the query below it loads only the translations for product. Despite some tries, I have no idea how to load property_translations.

```
@products = Product.includes(:properties).with_translations
```

#### Edit (1)

My goal is to load the 2 models with translations with eager loading. Right now, It loads products, product_translations and properties in a single query but not property_translations

I have also tried:

```
Product.with_translations.all(:include => { :properties => :property_translations }
```

But the issue here is there is no property_translations model (table created with Globalize3)

Thanks for your thought!

Comment: do you have declaration like "translates :sample_name" in your property model?

Comment: Yes I have my declarations set in my model, I completed my question with one other try and some more explanation of what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the answer from the following question: [Rails 3 includes translations globalize3 activerecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337086/rails-3-includes-translations-globalize3-activerecord?rq=1) which is:

```
@products = Product.includes([:translations, {:properties => :translations}])
```